# Cannot select password field by mouse! PHP site issue

Tags: html, css

The link is https://www.agarwalsaraogi.com/emailadmin

I can click on the username field but not on the password field. To place focus, I have to use the tab button on the keyboard.

It was working fine earlier but once I tried and entered an incorrect password. After that error, it's not working. I removed the error message line from the code but still it's not working. I used div class alert alert-danger for the error message.

The main issue is unable to enter password in mobile browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    $error = "";
    if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){

        /*** You can change username & password ***/
        $user = array(
                        "user" => "abc",
                        "pass"=>"def"          
                );
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if($username == $user['user'] && $pass == $user['pass']){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
            header("Location: Email_Manager.php");
            exit();
        }else{
            $error = "Invalid Login Credentials";
            echo "<script>alert('".$error."'); window.history.back();</script>";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
         <style>

.footer {
   height:60px;
   width: 99%;
   background-color: Transparent;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
}
.header {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
 /*  background-color: #4CAF50; */
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
.tableadjust {
   position: fixed;
   margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
   top: 30%;
   margin:auto;
}
</style>   

    <style>


    #grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: #2939B3; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,   #1385CC , #2939B3); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    }
#emails {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 512px;  
}

#emails td, #emails th {
    border: 0px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
}

/* #emails tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;} */

/* #emails tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;} */

#emails th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   /* background-color: #4CAF50; */
    color: white;

}
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=search] {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
    input[type=button], input[type=Submit], input[type=reset] {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     background-color: Transparent; 
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 3px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    </style>
    <title>
    Email Management
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    </head>
    <body id="grad1"><center>
    <div style="max-width: 512px; width:100%; margin: auto; top: 100px; position: relative;">
        <img src="favicon.png"></img>
    <table id="emails">
        <thead>
            <tr><th colspan=2>Login to Email Management
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <form method=POST action="index.php">
            <tr><td>Username: <td><input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" style="width:100%">
            <tr><td>Password: <td><input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" style="width:100%">
            <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Login" style="width:100%">
        </tbody>

    </table>

    </div>

    <footer class="footer"><br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
  <p style="width: 100%">Powered by <a href="http://www.byteitcorp.com" style="color:white;">ByteIT Corp</a></p>
</footer>
    </center>


<div class="header">
  <p><font size=25><b></b>EMAIL MANAGER</b></font></p>
</div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: your `<footer>` layer is above the password input

Comment: you tagged as php and this won't be of any help to you or anyone here. Post your source code here and not as an external resource.

Comment: As @Danielius mentioned removing the footer from your code fixes the issue. Not sure why you are using it, because it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thank you @Danielius. I see that might be the problem. But my footer does not stay down. I have used five <br> tags to adjust the footer. How do I do that?

Comment: *"PHP site issue"* - Going to your website won't help at all. All it's going to show us is parsed directives which transforms into HTML markup; totally useless if this is php related. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I removed the php tag; it was deceiving for people who follow that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the problem can be solved by removing the `position:relative;` from your `footer` class. Next time, you should know that if you need to use 6 `<br>`, you are doing something wrong. :)

edit:

1. remove `position:absolute` from `<font>` (where you have EMAIL MANAGER)
2. remove `position` from `<div style="max-width: 512px; width:100%; margin: auto; top: 100px; position: absolute;">`
3. move `font` with EMAIL MANAGER above `<div style="max-width: 512px; width:100%; margin: auto; top: 100px; position: absolute;">`

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the footer and have just kept the paragraph tag. but for some reason, it hides behind the password field

Comment: Is it better now, @AnkitSaraogi? Edited my answer

Comment: Yes it is better now. You can see that I have removed the footer tag completely. But I need to keep the text inside the last div tag. otherwise, it sets itself behind the password field which I am unable to understand

Comment: Well, you did a bit differently than I offered, but it is important that it works!

Comment: I am unsure if this is allowed or not but this is related to this website only. Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454056/css-acts-funny-in-iphone-but-works-perfectly-in-android-and-resized-browsers

Comment: @AnkitSaraogi I do not think that I can analyze that large piece of code now, try to google for specific Safari bugs in html, maybe they will help you. I always got annoyed by that safari lets-round-everything-to-make-it-look-ugly thing.

Comment: I am really frustrated since few days. The problem is that it's not about Safari. I tried chrome browser and other browsers in IOS and still the same. I am really sorry but I will be glad if you can just look into it. I guess the problem lies somewhere in the <table> with id emails2. You do not have to look into the entire thing.